# Calculator Web App - Handling Decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know JavaScript has issues with decimals because of the way computers handle them, etc. My question is how should they be handled in the context of a calculator web app?

```
var exampleDecimal = 1.2 + 0.64; // 1.8399999999999999 - INCORRECT
```

I have no idea what a user may enter, they may enter:

```
var exampleDecimal = (1.232 + 10.64) * 2 - 18.2 / 2.2; // 15.471272727272728 - CORRECT
```

I researched the topic and found that JavaScript does not have a simple solution for accurately working with decimals in the context of a basic calculator. Does jQuery? I couldn't find a solution on jQuery's reference website but I have little experience with jQuery.

Every JavaScript calculator tutorial I've found gets 1.2 + 0.64 wrong.

Comment: The second snippet won't result `1.839999...`, rather it results 15.4712727...

Comment: Try to use float for that values.

Comment: More read on related topic: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/

Comment: i meant this: myVar = parseFloat(myVar); . I thoiught this might help with that problem.

Comment: @Teemu --- That was a mistake, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery won't help you there, but you can use a library for handling this. One of the popular ones is [BigDecimal](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js):

```
var result = new BigDecimal('1.2').add(new BigDecimal('0.64'));
exampleDecimal.toString(); // 1.84
```

This syntax may be a little verbose, but you can wrap it to be a little more compact:

```
var dec = function (spec) {
  'use strict';
  if (this === undefined) { return new BigDecimal(spec); }
  return new BigDecimal(spec);
};
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var result = dec('1.2').add(dec('0.64'));
```